# Find Replace In Google Sheets App Scripts With Regex Not Working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have read many posts about this on SO. I am having trouble using Regex in google scripts for sheets.

I have a list of domains.

Goal: I want to remove all the path information from every domain in the list (everything after the `.*/`)

For example, I want to turn this:

`example.com/path-after-domain`

`example2.com/another-path-afterDomain`

into this:

`example1.com`

`example2.com`

Here is what I am trying to do.

### Looping and replace function

```
function replaceInSheet(values, to_replace, replace_with) {
  
  for(var row in values){
 
  var replaced_values = values[row].map(function(original_value) {
    return original_value.toString().replace(to_replace,replace_with)
  })
}
}
```

### Using the function by passing Regex

```
replaceInSheet(values, '((\/\w+)*\/)(.*)', "")
```

I also tested using `createtextfinder`. But I get an error when trying to use regex

```
const check = range.createTextFinder("((\/\w+)*\/)(.*)").useRegularExpression(true)

check.replaceWith("")
```

Note - I tested the regex with https://regex101.com/ and it successfully gets all path information

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `Goal: I want to remove all the path information from every domain in the list (everything after the .*/)`, I cannot understand your goal. Can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? And, which method do you want to achieve your goal using `Looping and replace function` or `I also tested using createtextfinder. `?

Comment: Hi thanks for your question, I updated the goal with two examples. I want to achieve the goal regardless of method.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to achieve the following conversion using Google Apps Script.

  - From

    ```
      example.com/path-after-domain, example2.com/another-path-afterDomain
    ```
  - To

    ```
      example1.com, example2.com
    ```

In this case, how about using `split` as follows?

#### Sample script:

```js
const values = ["example.com/path-after-domain", "example2.com/another-path-afterDomain"];
const res = values.map(e => e.split("/")[0]);
console.log(res) // [ 'example.com', 'example2.com' ]
```

#### Note:

- If you want to use this as a custom function, how about the following sample script? In this case, please put a custom function like `=SAMPLE(A1:A10)` to a cell.

  ```
    const SAMPLE = values => values.map(r => r.map(c => c.split("/")[0]));
  ```
- If you want to use TextFinder using your regex of `((\/\w+)*\/)(.*)`, how about the following sample script? In this case, please escape `\`. I thought that `\\/.*` might be able to be also used.

  ```
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder("((\\/\\w+)*\\/)(.*)").useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith("");
  ```

  - In this case, the column "A" is used.
- If the built-in function is used, how about the following sample formula?

  ```
    =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A,"/"),, 1)))

    =ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,"/.*",""))
  ```

#### Reference:

- [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: @Vinn Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.